# How HTTP request works in Django?

Tags: django, http, request, httpresponse

I have a question about how Django function can work properly and how they accept HTTP request and how function works.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def building_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        building = Building.objects.get(pk=pk)

    except Building.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = BuildingSerializer(building)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This is one of my code in my django app. When there is request with method 'GET' to the view, there would be only one data, request data from somewhere, when they get the data, but how they can distinguish(or maybe separate) which one is 'pk' and which one is 'request'?

Comment: Have you read [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/)? The short answer: when the Django framework calls your view function, the first argument given to your view function is always a `HttpRequest`. Why? The authors of Django chose to design Django in this way.

Comment: @Flux Thank you I couldn't understand whole documents so it happened. Guess I have to read documents more carefully. Thank you again!